# Show/Hide Specific groups of Objects on sheet using VBA

Tags: vba

On my sheet, I have:
3x setting buttons
3x menu buttons
6x sub menu buttons per menu button.

When I click one menu button:

- it's corresponding sub menu buttons should become visible
- all other sub menu buttons should be invisible
- menu buttons should stay visible
- setting buttons should stay visible

I am using the following naming convention:
Menu Button : Menu_01 , Menu_02, Menu_03
Sub Menu Buttons: 01_Sub1, 02_Sub1, 03_Sub1 ... 01_Sub6, 02_Sub6, 03_Sub6

I have done this, so the Menu number can be used as a flag for the SubMenu buttons
I have almost got it working using the following:

```
Sub OpenMenu()
Dim sObject As Shape
For Each sObject In ActiveSheet.Shapes
If Not InStr(sObject.Name, flagMenuID & "Sub") = 0 Then sObject.Visible = True
If Not InStr(sObject.Name, flagMenuID & "Sub") = 1 Then sObject.Visible = False

Next sObject

End Sub
```

Whilst this does successfully show the Sub Menu buttons for the correct Menu and hide the other Sub Menu buttons, it also appears to make all Menu buttons and Setting buttons invisible as well.

Can anyone suggest how I should modify this code to correct that? I understand that this may be a bit confusing, so if you have any questions, please ask and I will be happy to help!

Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: How is flagMenuId declared and what value does it have at this point?

Comment: Sub Menu()
flagMenuID = Replace(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name, "Menu_", "") & "_"

Call OpenMenu
End If
End Sub

Comment: Therefore, the value it should have is "01_", or "02_", or "03_"

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point on the sub and watching how it behaves? Checked to see that the values of variables (like flagMenuID) have their expected value? Using the various debugging capabilities of the Visual Basic Editor is hugely valuable to any programmer.

Comment: All you need is some additional test before hiding. Something like `If InStr(sObject.Name, flagMenuID & "Sub") <> 1 AND sObject.Name LIKE "*_Sub*" Then sObject.Visible = False`